# Dynamic "Filter by Condition" in Pivot

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i have a pivot table often required to adjust date range which up to 6 different dates from column A1 to A6. What kind of formula should i use in the "Filter By Condition" > "Custom Formula" based on the date references in A1:A6 so that i don't have to go to filter and select and deselect the date whenever i need the data? Appreciate your help here.

**[Updated: Google Sheet Trix here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IzDAwti4xnXVgJNfW2q1mrsha01yBkK_skTE_Xgb-uA/edit#gid=0)**

[image]

Comment: Please share a copy of the sheet, whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: I have updated the trix link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IzDAwti4xnXVgJNfW2q1mrsha01yBkK_skTE_Xgb-uA/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula to filter data based on the dates that you need and then construct a pivot table from there:

```
=FILTER(A2:F, MATCH(A2:A, N2:N7,0))
```

Note: `N2:N7` is the range of the dates that you want to filter. You may need to edit that range based on where you have that data.

The best way I found to achieve what you're looking for was filtering data first, then create a pivot table on the results.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do this without affecting data base ?